# UIView animation is clipping

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to make an animation but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I want the animation to be so that the menu enlarges just rolling down but it keeps clipping because of the constraint it will have after it is done enlarging.

I tried everything to my knowledge to try and change the order or just to keep the top anchored but until now I've been unsuccessful.

( See Imgur link for a gif with what I mean exactly, the sudden jump in position )

> menuHeightConstraint  is the constraint for the UIView height

code of the IBAction function

```
@IBAction func openMenu() {
        menuIsOpen.toggle()
        menuHeightConstraint.constant = menuIsOpen ? 180 : 55
        logoHorizontalConstraint.constant = menuIsOpen ? 0 : -122
        logoVerticalConstraint.constant = menuIsOpen ? 15 : 7
        logoHeight.constant = menuIsOpen ? 75 : 40
        logoWidth.constant = menuIsOpen ? 75 : 40
        loginVertConstraint.constant = menuIsOpen ? 100 : 15 // label constraint
        
        let indicator = menuIsOpen ? UIImage(systemName: "arrow.up.circle.fill") : UIImage(systemName: "arrow.down.circle.fill")
        
        dropDownButtonImage.setImage(indicator, for: .normal)
        
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 0.5,
            delay: 0,
            options: .curveEaseIn,
            animations: {
                self.menuView.layoutIfNeeded()
                
            },
            completion: nil)
    }
```

[Link to GIF -----](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0S9Y.jpg),
[constraint in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPHBT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `animations` block, change:

```
self.menuView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

to:

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: This did work! Thanks!